# JSON encoding/decoding with unicode in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, encoding

I <strike>upgraded</strike> downgraded to rails 2.3.17 due to the security bugs, but now I can't decode json strings that I have saved down to a DB if they have unicode in them :(. Is there a way to process the string such that it decodes properly?

```
e = ActiveSupport::JSON.encode({'a' => "Hello Unicode \u2019"})
ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(e)
```

gives me

```
RangeError: 8217 out of char range
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.17/lib/active_support/json/backends/okjson.rb:314:in `unquote'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.17/lib/active_support/json/backends/okjson.rb:251:in `strtok'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.17/lib/active_support/json/backends/okjson.rb:215:in `tok'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.17/lib/active_support/json/backends/okjson.rb:178:in `lex'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.17/lib/active_support/json/backends/okjson.rb:46:in `decode'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.17/lib/active_support/json/backends/okjson.rb:612:in `decode'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.17/lib/active_support/json/decoding.rb:14:in `decode'
from (irb):30
from /usr/local/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

I can't change the first line since it's coming from the DB like that.

This used to work.

Comment: Try not using ActiveSupport instead of the basic Jason library.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

- Switch to 2.3.15 which should be fine because that's when the fixes landed.
- Curse the developer who started this project in rails
- Begin work on porting to python post haste

Answer (score 3):

You can change the backend JSON provider in ActiveSupport.

Add `ActiveSupport::JSON.backend = "JSONGem"` into an application initialiser (I added it to  application.rb). This fixed the unicode parsing issues I had after I upgraded activesupport to 3.0.20.

See the [vulnerability notice which caused this update](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/rubyonrails-security/1h2DR63ViGo) - It mentions that this workaround should apply to 2.3.16 as well.

From rails console:

```
> ActiveSupport::VERSION::STRING
 => "3.0.20" 
> ActiveSupport::JSON.decode('{"test":"string\u2019"}')
RangeError: 8217 out of char range
> ActiveSupport::JSON.backend = "JSONGem" 
> ActiveSupport::JSON.decode('{"test":"string\u2019"}')
 => {"test"=>"string’"}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [JSON gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/json) will handle this correctly.

As a note, the gem is much more strict than the other JSON parsers out there. For example:

```
{ 'test' : 'value' }
```

This is not valid JSON even though it looks okay.

For whatever reason the non-UTF-8 savvy JSON parser shipped as part of the 2.3.16 patch which is really sloppy on the part of the maintainer.

Comment: Doesn't work because the values in the DB were encoded with ActiveSupport::JSON.encode, and I doubt the gem will be able to decode all values. I temporarily fixed it by upgrading from 2.3.17 to 2.3.15. I think it's just an active support bug.

Comment: Yikes. You could always spin through all your records, decode with the broken parser, encode with the working one, and save them in-place.